# Does a DynamicParameter Switch not read like a Static Parameter [switch]?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

Hopefully the Title is clear enough but, I am having some trouble understanding on how to evaluate against a *DynamicParameter Switch*, compared to a Static (*type casted*) switch.

In the following code block, there are 2 *switches* that become available **only** if the other 2 parameters are not null, and/or, are not empty:

- Add
- Remove

```
Function Test-DynamParam {
    Param (
        # Input Parameters
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false,
                   HelpMessage='Enter. Workflow. Name.')]
        [Alias('OMB','MailBox')]
        [string]$Workflow,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [Alias('EDIPI','DisplayName')]
        [string[]]$UserName

    )

      DynamicParam {
        if ($Workflow -ne $null -and $UserName -ne $null) {
          $parameterAttribute = [System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute]@{
              ParameterSetName = "AddingMembers"
              Mandatory = $false
          }

          $attributeCollection = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]]::new()
          $attributeCollection.Add($parameterAttribute)

          $dynParam1 = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new(
            'Add', [switch], $attributeCollection
          )

          $paramDictionary = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
          $paramDictionary.Add('Add', $dynParam1)
          

          $parameterAttribute1 = [System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute]@{
              ParameterSetName = "RemovingMembers"
              Mandatory = $false
          }

          $attributeCollection1 = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]]::new()
          $attributeCollection1.Add($parameterAttribute1)

          $dynParam11 = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new(
            'Remove', [switch], $attributeCollection1
          )

          $paramDictionary.Add('Remove', $dynParam11)
          return $paramDictionary

        }
      }

    Process {    
        $Add.IsPresent 
    }
}
```

Running:

- `Test-DynamParam -Workflow 'd' -UserName 'a' -Add`

returns empty.

Unfortunately, `$Add.IsPresent` is not evaluated to any *boolean* value regardless if the switch is present or not. Yet in this function it is (*which makes sense*):

```
Function Test-StaticParam {
    Param (

        [switch]$Add

    )

    $Add.IsPresent

}
```

Running:

- `Test-StaticParam -Add`

returns `True`.

**Question**

How can I evaluate against dynamic parameter chosen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `$PSBoundParameters` automatic variable:

```
Process {    
    $PSBoundParameters['Add'].IsPresent 
}
```

Comment: Glad smart people are up early! This worked for me. Thank ya! Also, wasn't aware that was a function of `$PSBoundParameters`; was using it like this instead: `$PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Add')` which didn't give me no result. Will accept the answer when it allows me to.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala The nice thing about `$PSBoundParameters` is it implements `IDictionary` - so you can treat it like any other dictionary/hashtable :-)